# Regex for range 7.2-80.0, decimal length not required

Tags: regex

Anyone see what's wrong with the below query? Trying to confirm a number is between or equal to 7.2 and 80 in regex. Multiple decimals don't matter for example 8.999 is fine.

```
^(?:80(?:\.0)?|[8-79](?:\.[0-9])?|7?:\.[2-9])$
```

Comment: Why don't you do it using the standard library functions? Most languages will give you something that could parse decimal values.

Comment: Also, just confirming, is it really `7.2-80.0`, and not `7.2-8.0`?

Answer (score 1):

Your character class [8-79] is not a valid way of matching integers 8 through 79. An integer range in a character class must be a range of one-digit integers. A proper way to match integers 8 through 79 would be:

```
(?:[89]|[1-7][0-9])
```

Also, you are only matching up to one decimal place. For example,

```
80(?:\.0)?
```

will match 80 and 80.0, but not 80.00. If this could cause a problem for your application, you would instead want to use

```
80(?:\.0+)?
```

Using these concepts, I think this regex should do what you want:

```
^(?:80(?:\.0+)?|(?:[89]|[1-7][0-9])(?:\.[0-9]+)?|7(?:\.[2-9][0-9]*)?)$
```

Comment: @CuriousGeorge Glad this answer helps! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.